# Values with colliding hashes

Tags: haskell

I need to test an algorithm, which revolves around the [`hash`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable-1.2.2.0/docs/Data-Hashable.html#v%3ahash) function. Since a hash collision is a hardly reproducible thing I need a few values, which are known to collide. So are there any known colliding values of the same type?

Comment: Why don't you go download a dictionary and collide away?

Comment: Is your algorithm polymorphic in the choice of the data type? In this case, you could just create a "fake" Hashable instance that always returns some constant. If that doesn't work, you could use a [Birthday Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)

Comment: In latest `hashable` (1.2.2.0) the integral types basically hash to themselves, and the salting is also rather thin (see `combine` in the source), so it's easy to find collisions (which might not be what you'd prefer... ).

Comment: @AndrásKovács Thanks, but bennofs has already solved my problem.

Comment: @bennofs You solved my problem. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I know the problem has already been solved, but why not just hash the same exact value over and over again? Then you're guaranteed collisions.

Comment: @BenjaminKovach As well, as pretty much any hashing-based algorithm, mine checks for equality of values in case of hash collision. Hence, feeding it with the same value won't test the execution branch, which accommodates to equal hashes and unequal values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion by @bennofs, here's an artificial instance with a hash value colliding for half a range of `Word8` values.

```
newtype CollidingValue = CollidingValue Word8
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Hashable CollidingValue where
  hashWithSalt salt (CollidingValue w) =
    if w > edge
      then hashWithSalt salt (w - edge)
      else hashWithSalt salt w
    where
      edge = 128
```